# Does Macbook (Apple computers) resume running programs after waking up from hibernating/sleep?

Tags: mac, sleep

I started running a Matlab program on my Mac last night at 11:00 PM, the program is estimated to last about 6 hours. However, it seems it went to sleep/standby/hibernating mode after a few hours (< 6 hours). Next morning, I woke it up and left it there. The program finished at 10:00 AM in the morning. My tic/toc (Matlab timing method) shows that the program elapsed 3.5 hours.

I am wondering if mac can actually resume a running program after waking up. Thanks!

Comment: I would yes, seeing as how it did. But, you didn't provide which OSX you're running.

Comment: @Raystafarian This is OSX 10.9.5